# Transform a div without transforming icon inside

Tags: css, css-transitions, css-animations, css-transforms

I am attempting to transform a `div` on hover using the CSS transform properties.

I have the transform doing what I want, but unfortunately its applying the transform (logically I guess), to the contents of the `div` I want to just apply the transform the `div` but not the underlying content (an Icon in this case).

I have seen a few methods on here, including applying the reverse transition to the icon, but when I did that it just multiplied the effect.

Here is [my code](https://jsfiddle.net/AntonZdz/ndh7xj6s/1/):

```css
.MsgBtnIcon {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 7px;
  padding: 0px;
}
#transDemo2 div {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
}
#transDemo2 div:hover,
#transDemo2 div.hover_effect {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2, 2) translateX(-19px) translateY(-19px);
  -moz-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2, 2) translateX(-19px) translateY(-19px);
  -ms-transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2, 2) translateX(-19px) translateY(-19px);
  transform: rotate(360deg) scale(2, 2) translateX(-19px) translateY(-19px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/353bc64522.js"></script>
<div id="transDemo2">
  <div class="hover">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-4x MsgBtnIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to undo **all** the transformations or just the scale? - https://jsfiddle.net/ndh7xj6s/2/

Comment: so you want the background to spin and scale up but the icon to stay in place and not scale up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this by moving the `MsgBtnIcon` to be a child of the hover div and add `pointer-events: none`.

## [Updated fiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/ndh7xj6s/5/)

```css
.MsgBtnIcon {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right:  7px;
  padding: 0px; 
  pointer-events: none;
}
#transDemo2 div {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  right: 0px; 
  background-color: #03A9F4;
  width: 75px;
  height: 75px;
  text-align:center;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 1s ease-in-out;

}

#transDemo2 div:hover, #transDemo2 div.hover_effect {
  -webkit-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(2,2) translateX(-19px) translateY(-19px);
  -moz-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(2,2) translateX(-19px) translateY(-19px);
  -ms-transform:rotate(360deg) scale(2,2) translateX(-19px) translateY(-19px);
  transform:rotate(360deg) scale(2,2) translateX(-19px) translateY(-19px);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/353bc64522.js"></script>

<div id="transDemo2">
  <div class="hover"></div>
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-4x MsgBtnIcon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect thank! I ended up doing a variation of this onClick rather than hover, but your comments definately got me closer to my end goal so thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Rather than fighting against the transform, maybe it would be better to simply separate the part that suffers the transformation from the part that stays unnafected:
https://jsfiddle.net/m1hqzaqf/

```
<script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/353bc64522.js"></script>

<div id="transDemo2">
  <div class="hover">
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-plus fa-4x MsgBtnIcon" aria-hidden="true">X</i>
</div>
```

After all, the 'hover' div, in this instance, seems to be there just to pose as a background, anyway.

Comment: Any reasons for the downvote? One can't correct something unless one knows what's wrong.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but your updated jsfiddle doesn't work like it should